# Does Windows' VS Code recognize tilde (~) character when requiring modules?

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, npm, commonjs

I am developing from a source code that was created using a UNIX-based system. I am using Windows-based system and there are a lot of modules required using the tilde character. Somehow, my VS Code cannot detect the required module, but when I use relative or absolute path, the code works.

Example:

```
const { createConnection } = require('~/db')
```

Does this mean that VS Code in Windows cannot require modules using the tilde character? Or do I just have to change some config settings?

Comment: VS Code doesn't do the requiring, whatever runtime (e.g. Node) or bundler (e.g. Webpack) you're using does. What's the _intent_ of that, are you trying to import from your actual home directory?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm using Node, no bundler. The intent is to import from the `(root of project)/src/`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a NodeJS/CommonJS thing than a VS Code thing. Actually- it's not a VS Code thing at all.

From my testing, the answer is no- not even on a UNIX system.

You can find docs on how NodeJS does module resolution at https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#all-together.

Tilde as a shortcut for "user home directory" is usually a shell-level thing. Ex. Bash (docs here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

Though you could define [TypeScript path aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) and configure your JS bundler (if you are using one) to have corresponding aliases (Ex. [webpack alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)) (or your webserver to handle requests with such paths).

Comment: Thank you. This means that I have to manually change all the imports that use tilde character to relative or absolute paths...

Comment: @Richard see the edit I just made.

Comment: Alright, that is if I'm using a JS Bundler. Unfortunately, I am not :-( I think I'll just update the require statements to use absolute and relative paths for now.

Comment: I just found out about `jsconfig.json`. Does that help with what the tilde character means?

Comment: @Richard you could use it to define path aliases. Just make sure to set up your server to supports those paths if your frontend is going to make requests with tildes in them.